# sort files before converting to pdf in imagemagick

Tags: sorting, unix, pdf, imagemagick, pipe

I have a folder full of image files I need to convert to a pdf.  I used wget to download them.  The problem is the ordering linux gives the files isn't the actual order of the pages, this is an example of the file ordering:

```
100-52b69f4490.jpg
101-689eb36688.jpg
10-1bf275d638.jpg
102-6f7dc2def9.jpg
103-2da8842faf.jpg
104-9b01a64111.jpg
105-1d5e3862d8.jpg
106-221412a767.jpg
...
```

I can convert these images to a pdf using imagemagick, with the command 
`convert *.jpg output.pdf`

but it'll put the pages into that pdf in the above order, not in human readable numerical order 1-blahblahblah.jpg, 2-blahblahblah.jpg, 3-blahblahblah.jpg etc.

Is the easiest way to do this pipe the output of sort to convert?  or to pipe my wget to add each file as I'm getting it to a pdf file?

Answer (score 11):

`convert $(ls -1v *.jpg) book.pdf`

worked for me

Comment: Thanx this really worked a treat and very simple syntax. Much appreciated

Answer (score 7):

There are several options:

The simplest is as follows, but may overflow your command-line length if you have too many pages:

```
convert $(ls *jpg | sort -n) result.pdf
```

Next up is feeding the list of files on `stdin` like this:

```
ls *jpg | sort -n | convert @- result.pdf
```

Comment: Perfect! I had the exact same problem

Comment: Great answer, thanks. It should be worth mentioning that integers should be of the same decimal format. For example, 600 will be treated as > 1400. A simple solution would be to save all files with a common format. That is, 0600 and 1400 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here one *bash* script to do it that:

```
#!/bin/bash
sort -n < list.txt > sorted_list.tmp
readarray -t list < sorted_list.tmp
convert "${list[@]}" output.pdf
rm sorted_list.tmp
exit
```

You can get `list.txt` by first listing your directory with `ls > list.txt`.
The `sort -n` (numerical sort) "normalizes" your entries.
The sorted list is saved in the `.tmp` file and deleted at the end.
Greetings,